# Copiar datos de otra hoja en otro libro a mi hoja actual

Tags: excel

estoy tratando de copiar los datos de otra hoja de calculo a mi libro actual, pero me da error al momento de hacer el copiado en mi destino, imprimo mi rango automáticamente y me da el rango, lo inserto de forma manual, pero aun así no lo reconoce

Este es el rango calculado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código:

```
Sub CopyExport()
Dim Origen As Range    
Dim Destino As Range    
Dim ini As String    
Dim fin As String

ini = "A" & (ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row) + 1    
fin = "AI"    
rango = ini & ":" & fin    
MsgBox (rango)

Set Origen = Workbooks("exportD.xlsm").Worksheets("Exportar").Columns("A:AI")    
Set Destino = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Hoja1").Range("A100880:AI")

Origen.Copy Destino

End Sub
```

y este es el error que me da:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Hay 2 problemas.

**1.- en** `Set Origen = Workbooks("exportD.xlsm").Worksheets("Exportar").Columns("A:AI")`

Eso devuelve 1048576 filas, es decir, todas las filas de la hoja, asi que estarías seleccionando una enorme cantidad de celdas porque tambien son muchas columnas.

En lugar de `Columns`, puedes usar `Range` para definir `Destino`, algo asi:

```
Set Origen = Workbooks("exportD.xlsm").Worksheets("Exportar").Range("A1:AI200")
```

Si no conoces el numero de la ultima fila, puedes obtenerla asi:

```
uFila = Workbooks("exportD.xlsm").Worksheets("Exportar").UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

**Por lo que `Origen` queda asi:**

```
Set Origen = Workbooks("exportD.xlsm").Worksheets("Exportar").Range("A1:AI" & uFila)
```

**2.- en** `Set Destino = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Hoja1").Range("A100880:AI100880")`

En el Destino no es necesario indicar la columna final, solo con indicar el rango inicial es suficiente para pegar.

**Por lo tanto, `Destino` queda asi:**

```
Set Destino = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Hoja1").Range("A100880")
```